# Show only, when taxonomy has posts?

Tags: taxonomy, query

I'd like to query posts by taxonomy like this:

```
<?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'movies', 'string');
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

if(!empty($terms)){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        query_posts( array(
        'movies' => $term->slug,
        'showposts' => 4,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
        if(have_posts()){
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
do stuff 

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But I only want to show this, while there are posts with the same taxonomy to show up.

How could I do this?

Something like: if has taxonomy AND has post?

Thanks!

AD

Comment: Do mean posts other than the current one? `get_the_terms` will return terms that belong to this post - and so it follows each term has at least one post associated to it :)

Comment: aha....ok...I will try something else :)

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at [the array that `get_the_terms()` returns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#Returns), you'll see that it includes a "count".

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to find all posts with a count greater than 1 (i.e. terms that are on more than the current post). So, I think you can simply change your `foreach` statement to this (the second line is the change):

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  if( $term->count > 1 ) {
    query_posts( array(
    'movies' => $term->slug,
    'showposts' => 4,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate ) );
    if(have_posts()){
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
              // do stuff 
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
    }
  }
}
```

Also, `get_the_terms()` only accepts two parameters (at least according to the Codex), so I'm not sure on what that third parameter is doing. It's possibly not doing anything? If you're trying to get terms from two taxonomies, check out [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

Comment: dear mrwweb thanks for the reply. It's kind of a related post on taxonomies. So when theres a post about "Pulp Fiction" with a slug e.g. "pulp-fiction" and another somewhere around, this should be featured. If no other post has this slug, the related posts shouldn't be shown. I tried it, but nothing is showing up... I put your code into mine, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If this is a related posts loop, then you should be using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` (I prefer the latter). With `query_posts()` you may be getting arguments that you don't want. If you go with WP_Query, then you'll need to use a `tax_query` instead of 'movies' => $term->slug, but the documentation on the codex is easy to follow. What showed up before you changed the code?